# Pass awk output to dialog checklist

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting, dialog

I want to display a list of databases with their sizes using `dialog checklist`, but get some mess. Removing space between size and the word "MB" helps, but I don't know how to preserve it and make normal output.

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash

db_list_command="
SELECT table_schema, ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1)
FROM information_schema.tables
GROUP BY table_schema;
"
db_list=$(echo $db_list_command | mysql -N)
dialog_options=$(echo "$db_list" | awk '{print $1 " \"" $2 " MB\" off"}')

dialog --checklist "Select databases" 40 60 20 $dialog_options 2>/tmp/dout.txt
db_selected=$(</tmp/dout.txt)

echo $db_selected
```

Output of code above:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdOtO.jpg

Output w/o spaces between size and MB, but now with unwanted extra quotes:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/78ufW.jpg

I would like to get normal checklist with size in format like `5.8 MB`
How to do that?

p.s. If I echo awk command to terminal and then copy&paste to dialog manually - everything is normal!

Comment: What does `dialog_options` contains? Please add `echo "$dialog_options"` so we can have a clue what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to preserve spaces :

```
#!/bin/bash

db_list_command="
SELECT table_schema, ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1)
FROM information_schema.tables
GROUP BY table_schema;
"

declare -a dialog_options
while read -r db size; do
    dialog_options+=("$db" "$size MB" off)
done < <(echo $db_list_command | mysql -N)


dialog --checklist "Select databases" 40 60 20 "$dialog_options[@]}" 2>/tmp/dout.txt
db_selected=$(</tmp/dout.txt)

echo $db_selected
```